# Make 2 SQL select queries from 2 tables inside an other select query

Tags: sql, select, merge

I have 2 SQL tables: `"episode"` and `"topic"`, each topic and episode have a video (an episode contains several topics but it is not important for my problem). They have their own fields but they have `"title", "date", "video_url"` and `"count"` in common (count is the number of times the video is watched).

I would like to make a top-5 selection based on the count field with only one query.

So I need to merge the query:

```
select title, date, video_url, count from episode order by count desc
```

and the same query with "from topic".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 select top 5 *
 from
 (
      select title, date, video_url, count from episode
      union all
      select title, date, video_url, count from topic
 ) as A
 order by count desc
```

you can add type name to find out is it episode or topic. Also you can add `top` 5 into subquery so server will know he don't need to get all the records

```
 select top 5 *
 from
 (
      select top 5 title, date, video_url, count, 'episode' as type_name from episode order by count desc
      union all
      select top 5 title, date, video_url, count, 'topic' as type_name from topic order by count desc
 ) as A
 order by count desc
```

Comment: Good answer the first one since it also leaves room for elimination of the same videos. If you put a Select Distinct Top 5 * etc etc

Comment: I've added `top 5` into subquery to be sure optimizer will not get more than 5 records from each table before merge. I don't know if I need to eliminate videos so I've not added `distinct`

Comment: Yeah this is even better. But I was talking about the possibility of 1 video with the MOST views existing both in an episode and a topic. Then it would still pass into the merge from both tables (as row number 1) and would be the first 2 rows of the resulting selection.